# Adding tag input in post form

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, tags

So, I have following form in my plugin for post upload (wordpress):

```
if(empty($_POST['post_id'])){

    $post = array(
        'post_content'   => 'Dummy Content', 
        'post_title'     => 'Dummy Title',          
        'post_status'    => 'inherit',      
        'post_type'      => 'post' 
    ); 
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post, true );

}else{
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
}
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$files = $_FILES['files'];
foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {            
    if ($files['name'][$key]) { 
        $filename = rand() . '' . $files['name'][$key];
        $file = array( 

            //Here goes other irrelevant code

        ); 
        $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );

        $image_path[]     = array(
                    'image_path' => $upload_dir['url'] . '/' . $filename,
                    'meta_key'   => 'upload_image',
                    'meta_value' => $upload_dir['url'] . '/' . $filename,
                    'post_id'    => $post_id
                );

        add_post_meta($post_id, 'upload_image', $upload_dir['url'] . '/' . $filename );
    } 
} 
echo json_encode($image_path);
exit;
```

Above function adds an image as a post with dummy contents such as title/description etc.

Now, if I want to update the content, then I can do so by following:

```
global $wpdb;
$tags = $_POST['rh_tags'];  
if(!empty($_POST['post_id'])){          
    $data = array(
            'post_title'   => $_POST['title'],
            'post_content' => $_POST['content'],
            'tags_input'     => $tags,
            'post_status'  => 'publish'

      );
      $where = array('ID' => $_POST['post_id']);
      $update =  $wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix . 'posts' , $data, $where, $format = null, $where_format = null );       
}else{      
    $post = array(
        'post_title'     => $_POST['title'], 
        'post_content'   => $_POST['content'],      
        'post_status'    => 'publish', 
        'tags_input'     => $tags,  
        'post_type'      => 'post' 
    ); 
    wp_insert_post($post);      
}
echo 'success';
exit;
```

Here I added `'tags_input'     => $tags,` to add a post tag.

Here is current situation:

**1. No image selected:** in the input field (a form with simple input field with title, description and tag), if I add something to the tag input while there is no image selected, then the post is created properly with the tag.

**2. Image selected:** if an image is selected, then with the tag input, it does not create the post at all.

I tried to add `'tags_input'     => $tags,` in the very first function, but that did not work either.

Can someone point out what change I need to make in my first function?

Comment: I don't see where you declare `$image_path` in your first snippet.

Comment: I edited to add `$image_path` in the first function.

Comment: enable erros => `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and run the script, check if you get any error.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you add some `var_dump` statements if this is still a problem. When followed by an `exit;` statement, this will immediately show the data in the object.

I'd want to look at the state of the data within each if/then statement and the expected data in each function.

Of course, the data before and after your image is created/uploaded. Then I would expect the problem to become visible.

So generally, I'd do the following to debug the issue.

At various places put the following debugging code and you may also add the different critical variables using a comma separator in the var_dump function:

```
var_dump($_POST); 
exit;
```

> You also should consider using better variable names because the code
>   is more confusing to debug than it needs to be. The variable names are
>   not consistent even within a single if/then loop for example in the
>   second function you mention $data and then $post.